# Orchard Custom Theme - Create 2 additional navigation menus, only visible on certain pages

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I have a custom themed orchard site - I am new to Orchard.

All pages have the same header with primary navigation, and footer. I have set header & footer up as Zones.

There are 4 main sections, 2 require a second navigation on the left; Information & FAQ.

I would like to dynamically create pages for those sections in the CMS - and have the page added to the appropriate second navigation menu, then when clicked navigate to that page (showing the correct navigation menu on the left - with the right styling for the rest of the page).

In simple steps what's the best way to do this - and does it need me to edit the Layout or other files in Visual Studio (I can if required).

I have found several articles on this online - but they all apply to completed themes, not one being created from scratch.

(I also don't have this 'map' of the site on the widgets page - how / should I create one somehow?):
[image: site map on widgets page]

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As i understood what you are after is creating a `Widget`. Basically to show any content in your page you must create appropriate `ContentType` and attach required parts to it , and to display it you must enter `url` of that content in browser's address bar or click in a link for that content which in either case it will navigate to a new page and will display content inside `[Content] Zone`. but if you want to display a Content in a special `Zone` and special pages, Creating a `Widget` is the way to go.to create a widget the only thing required is to add a `WidgetPart` to it and give it Stereotype of 'Widget'.you can do this by making following changes in `Migration` file for your desired `ContentType` :

```
ContentDefinitionManager.AlterTypeDefinition("MyType", cfg => cfg
                .WithPart("WidgetPart")
                .WithPart("CommonPart")
                .WithSetting("Stereotype", "Widget"));
```

this will turn your `Content Type` into a widget which can be placed in any Zone you want.

to add your widget to a Zone navigate to widgets from dashboard.

[image]

and then select the zone which you want to place your widget in :

[image]

and then select your widget

[image]

and finally select the layer in which your widget will be shown.a layer is set of rules which determine in which pages your widget will be displayed.for example selecting `homepage` will display your widget only in home page, selecting `default` will display your widget in all pages and so on.to define your own rule check [here](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Managing-widgets#AddingaLayer).

[image]

**Edit :**

to create new `zone` in your theme just include the `Zone` name in `theme.txt` file then open up `Layout.cshtml` (one resides in your custom theme's view directory) , and do following :

given your zone name is `SecondaryNavigation` then add following code inside your theme

```
@if (Model.SecondaryNavigation != null)
{
    <div id="secondary-navigation" class="group">
        <div class="inner">
            @Zone(Model.SecondaryNavigation)
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

with this an additional `Zone` will be displayed in zone list and then you can put your widget inside your newly created `zone`.and about that picture you asked about.it is an image file which created by author of the theme and named 'Theme.png' and will displayed as a preview in manage widget screen , you can create it for your own theme and put it in your theme view directory.

**EDIT 2**

The migration file itself is not important.the only thing which is important is to define a class which drives from `DataMigrationImpl` , orchar will pick your migration file and run it automatically , migration file has firstly a `Create` method which returns 1 , and for each further update you must define a method called `UpdateFromN` in which `N` is current version your module is in, that  will return  2 , 3 , ...  what you can do in a migration file is creating database tables , creating `ContentTypes` , `ContentParts` , `ContentFields` , etc. there is already couple of modules shipped with orchard , check them and get the idea.

Comment: Thanks. This is a custom theme I'm making myself. I have listed 2 zones in the Theme.txt file - but what is required to 'put them on the page'? Also I only have the standard layers available - do I need a new layer for this?

Comment: Thanks. What is the migration for / what is a stereotype?

Comment: So each of my, say, 4 layouts would have a different widget - 2 with different secondary navigations - and 2 with no additional navigation - correct?

Comment: To clarify - in any of these layouts, with the nav - the user may want to create 10, or 50 pages themselves, each with a new URL. This allows that right?

Comment: could you tell me the name / location of where I need to place that migration code - and why it is required / why can't it just be done in the CMS directly? thx

Comment: have you saw orchard documentation page ? if not check http://docs.orchardproject.net/ - any thing described there.

Comment: I have - just all seems rather complicated - will try again.

Comment: but without reading you can't learn concepts.if i want to describe migrations here i will write all the same stuff as in documentation .many people learn orchard with these documents.

Comment: just 1 question - which migrations file should that go in - there are a lot. Will a build make it work?

Comment: the migration file itself is not important.the only thing which is important is to define a class which drives from `DataMigrationImpl` , orchar will pick your migration file and run it automatically , migration file has firstly a `Create` method which returns 1 , and for each further update it will return  2 , 3 , ...  what you can do in a migration file is creating database tables , creating `ContentTypes` , `ContentParts` , `ContentFields`. there is already couple of modules shipped with orchard , check them and get the idea.